# Python only spawning 2 threads

Tags: python, multithreading

take a look at this little code piece:

```
for server in serverlist:
    while(threading.activeCount() >= maxThreads):
        time.sleep(0.5)     
    threading.Thread(target=pingServer, args=server).start()
    print("Number of Threads running: " + str(threading.activeCount()))
```

serverlist contains a large number of hosts (1000+). For each entry, the for-loop creates and starts a new thread with the pingServer-function (which pings a server). To ensure that not to many threads are spawned, there is a while loop with the maxThreads.

HOWEVER, Whether maxThreads is 2, 5, 10 or 100. Python never spawns more than 2 Threads so the list takes forever.

Even if i remove the while loop (where it should spawn unlimited # of threads) it will only spawn 2 threads at max.

Why is this?

Comment: Note, if server is a string, the call should be `threading.Thread(target=pingServer, args=(server,)).start()`. Not sure if that is related to the threading count issue though.

Comment: Please add to the code listing `pingServer`'s implementation (or at least the def for it).

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the answers. I actually found out what the problem was.

Part of the pingServer did some logging and was locking a file which made everything else wait.